# How to get API call from WordPress with react js and axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**I have a problem, I can't get data from WordPress API with axios react js
my code:**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var axios = require('axios');

var Wordpress = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {posts: []};
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost/scareid/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`).then(res => {
            const posts = res.data.map(obj => obj.data);
            this.setState({posts});
        });
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <h1>{`/r/${this.props.title}`}</h1>
                <ul>

                    {this.state.posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

module.exports = Wordpress;
```

My API

http://pastebin.com/9x4rgJmE

Console log data:

[image]

Comment: Is that console log coming?

Comment: console log data by image

Comment: jsx error screenshoot http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-02-27_at_9.33.08_PM.png

Comment: Yes but I can't see what the error is. Can you put a breakpoint on this line and check the response:

const posts = res.data.map(obj => obj.data);

Comment: may be like this ? http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-02-27_at_9.53.00_PM.png

Comment: First of all, you should always have error handling in your code. Add a check for `if (res && res.data)` before attempting to do `res.data.map.`

Secondly, what does `axios.get` return here? Can you do `console.log(res)`?

Comment: console log for res http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-02-27_at_10.11.54_PM.png & http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-02-27_at_10.24.26_PM.png
and this data from localhost http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-02-27_at_10.12.52_PM.png

Comment: i use console.log(res.data.map(obj => obj)); and result like this http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-02-27_at_10.39.33_PM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it.

You don't need the map step at all, the array is already returned in res.

Replace:

```
const posts = res.data.map(obj => obj.data);
            this.setState({posts});
```

with:

```
if (res && res.data) {
 this.setState({
  posts: res.data 
 });
}
```

Comment: but i have problem in return 
in this error {this.state.posts.map(posts => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)}

but i console.log(this.state.posts.map(posts => posts.id)); like that 
output is id posts

Comment: thanks this is work {this.state.posts.map(data => <li key={data.id}>{data.title.rendered}</li>)}
thanks for help me, i apologize very troublesome you
Thank you for the help
Thank you for your help, because I just learned react js one week